# Return similar values ​from multiple array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Guys I made a simple example to illustrate my problem. I have 3 object arrays, `datasOne`, `datasTwo` and `datasThree` and what I want is to return a new array only with the objects that are in the 3 arrays. For example, if there is only *Gustavo* in the 3 arrays, then he will be returned. But there is a detail that if the `datasThree` is an empty array, then it will bring the data in common only from `datasOne` and `datasTwo` and if only the `datasTwo` which has data and the other two arrays have empty, then it will return data only from `datasTwo`. In other words it is to return similar data only from arrays that have data. I managed to do this algorithm and it works the way I want, but I would like to know another way to make it less verbose and maybe simpler and also work in case I add more arrays to compare like a `dataFour` for example. I appreciate anyone who can help me.

My code below:

```js
let datasOne = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Ana' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alice' }
]

let datasTwo = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Alice' }
]

let datasThree = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Luiz' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Ana' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Kelly' },
  { id: 4, name: 'David' }
]

let filtered

if (datasOne.length > 0 && datasTwo.length > 0 && datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasOne.filter(firstData => {
    let f1 = datasThree.filter(
      secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id
    ).length
    let f2 = datasTwo.filter(
      secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id
    ).length
    if (f1 && f2) {
      return true
    }
  })
} else if (datasOne.length > 0 && datasTwo.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasOne.filter(firstData => {
    return datasTwo.filter(secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id).length
  })
} else if (datasOne.length > 0 && datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasOne.filter(firstData => {
    return datasThree.filter(secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id)
      .length
  })
} else if (datasTwo.length > 0 && datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasTwo.filter(firstData => {
    return datasThree.filter(secondData => firstData.id === secondData.id)
      .length
  })
} else if (datasThree.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasThree
} else if (datasTwo.length > 0) {
  filtered = datasTwo
} else if (datasOne.length) {
  filtered = datasOne
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Does an array have unique object only once? Is is possible if an array has `{ id: 1, name: 'Gustavo' }` twice?

Comment: Is is possible to have 2 `id` to different person?

Comment: No. Id will be unique for each person. In the algorithm I made, the return of 'filtered' will be [ { "id": 1, "name": "Gustavo"}, { "id": 3, "name": "Luiz"}] because these objects arefound in the 3 arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can first [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array which is not empty in `arrs`.

```
const arrs = [datasOne, datasTwo, datasThree].filter((a) => a.length);
```

**2)** Flatten the `arrs` array using [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```
arrs.flat()
```

**3)** Loop over the flatten array and count the occurrence of all objects using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
const map = new Map();
for (let o of arrs.flat()) {
  map.has(o.id)
    ? (map.get(o.id).count += 1)
    : map.set(o.id, { ...o, count: 1 });
}
```

**4)** Loop over the `map` and collect the result only if it is equal to `arrs.length`

```
if (count === arrs.length) result.push(rest);
```

---

```js
let datasOne = [
  { id: 1, name: "Gustavo" },
  { id: 2, name: "Ana" },
  { id: 3, name: "Luiz" },
  { id: 8, name: "Alice" },
];

let datasTwo = [
  { id: 1, name: "Gustavo" },
  { id: 3, name: "Luiz" },
  { id: 8, name: "Alice" },
];

let datasThree = [
  { id: 1, name: "Gustavo" },
  { id: 3, name: "Luiz" },
  { id: 2, name: "Ana" },
  { id: 5, name: "Kelly" },
  { id: 4, name: "David" },
];

const arrs = [datasOne, datasTwo, datasThree].filter((a) => a.length);

const map = new Map();
for (let o of arrs.flat()) {
  map.has(o.id)
    ? (map.get(o.id).count += 1)
    : map.set(o.id, { ...o, count: 1 });
}

const result = [];
for (let [, obj] of map) {
  const { count, ...rest } = obj;
  if (count === arrs.length) result.push(rest);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect. Very smart! Thanks for answering bro

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure it cover all edge cases, but this might get you on the right track:

```js
function filterArrays(...args) {
  const arraysWithData = args.filter((array) => array.length > 0);
  const [firstArray, ...otherArrays] = arraysWithData;

  return firstArray.filter((item) => {
    for (const array of otherArrays) {
      if (!array.some((itemTwo) => itemTwo.id === item.id)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
}
```

Usage:

```js
const filtered = filterArrays(datasOne, datasTwo, datasThree);
console.log(filtered)
```

I believe the code is fairly readable, but if something is not clear I'm glad to clarify.

Comment: Very good friend. Another smart alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function merge(arr){
  arr = arr.filter(item=>item.length>0)
  const map = {};
  arr.forEach(item=>{
    item.forEach(obj=>{
      if(!map[obj.id]){
        map[obj.id]=[0,obj];
      }
      map[obj.id][0]++;
    })
  })
  const len = arr.length;
  const ret = [];
  Object.keys(map).forEach(item=>{
    if(map[item][0]===len){
      ret.push(map[item][1])
    }
  })
  return ret;
}
merge([datasOne,datasTwo,datasThree])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).